# Determinate spinning NSProgressIndicator doesn't adapt to frame size and gets cut off

Tags: cocoa

The following code should produce 6 spinning progress indicators of varying sizes: 3 indeterminate and 3 determinate ones. The first two of the 3 determinate ones are either entirely or partially cut off, which doesn't happen with the indeterminate ones. What's the problem?

[image]

```
var progress = NSProgressIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 16, height: 16))
progress.style = .spinning
view.addSubview(progress)

progress = NSProgressIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
progress.style = .spinning
view.addSubview(progress)

progress = NSProgressIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
progress.style = .spinning
view.addSubview(progress)

progress = NSProgressIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 0, width: 16, height: 16))
progress.style = .spinning
progress.isIndeterminate = false
progress.doubleValue = 50
progress.maxValue = 100
view.addSubview(progress)

progress = NSProgressIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
progress.style = .spinning
progress.isIndeterminate = false
progress.doubleValue = 50
progress.maxValue = 100
view.addSubview(progress)

progress = NSProgressIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
progress.style = .spinning
progress.isIndeterminate = false
progress.doubleValue = 50
progress.maxValue = 100
view.addSubview(progress)
```

Comment: Apparently the indeterminate ones do scale and the determinate ones don't. Have you tried the `controlSize` property?

Comment: You could also look at `intrinsicContentSize` and `sizeToFit()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Since the indeterminate spinning one worked with every size, I assumed that this would be the right way to size the determinate one as well, but using `controlSize` effectively works for both. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the circular determinate `NSProgressIndicator` doesn't scale. Use the `controlSize` property to set the size.